# Cannot iterate through the JSON object because of the unwanted keys

Tags: json, flutter, dart, httprequest

My JSON response object is like this

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "message": "done",
    "data": {
        "orders": {
            "order4": {
                "OrderId": "4",
                "OrderSubTotal": "568",
                "Items": {
                    "1": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                        "ItemDiscount": "10",
                        "Quantity": "3",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                        "ItemDiscount": "0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                    }
                },
                "order6": {
                    "OrderId": "6",
                    "total": "789",
                    "Items": {
                        "1": {
                            "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                            "ItemDiscount": "10",
                            "Quantity": "3",
                            "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                        },
                        "2": {
                            "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                            "ItemDiscount": "0",
                            "Quantity": "5",
                            "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot iterate through the fields since I am getting random keys like order6,order4. So is there a way to remove those keys from the object and create a nice clean JSON object. I coding in dart language.

Comment: which language you are using ?

Comment: flutter framework with dart. I added that in the description.

Comment: your json is a string ?

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: i mean if the json is just a string so that we need to serialize it before.

Comment: yes. It's a string

Comment: what do you mean by "random" keys. If you want to remove something from the JSON object you need to iterate through it and remove that specific node. If the data returned to you is wrong than check the source of the data.

Comment: json that you provided has an order 6 object inside the order 4  Object is it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I figured out what you want then `SplayTreeMap.from(map, comparator)` can do the job for you as the code below:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  String str = r'''{
    "response": "success",
    "message": "done",
    "data": {
        "orders": {
            "order6": {
                "OrderId": "6",
                "total": "789",
                "Items": {
                    "1": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                        "ItemDiscount": "10",
                        "Quantity": "3",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                        "ItemDiscount": "0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                    }
                }
            },
            "order4": {
                "OrderId": "4",
                "OrderSubTotal": "568",
                "Items": {
                    "1": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                        "ItemDiscount": "10",
                        "Quantity": "3",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                        "ItemDiscount": "0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}''';
  
  final sortedMap = new SplayTreeMap<String,dynamic>.from(jsonDecode(str)["data"]["orders"], (a,b)=>a.compareTo(b));
  print(sortedMap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check out this example that I have made based on the json you provided :

Following is your sample json that you provided:

```
{
    "response": "success",
    "message": "done",
    "data": {
        "orders": {
            "order6": {
                "OrderId": "6",
                "total": "789",
                "Items": {
                    "1": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                        "ItemDiscount": "10",
                        "Quantity": "3",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                        "ItemDiscount": "0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                    }
                }
            },
            "order4": {
                "OrderId": "4",
                "OrderSubTotal": "568",
                "Items": {
                    "1": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 1",
                        "ItemDiscount": "10",
                        "Quantity": "3",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "161.865"
                    },
                    "2": {
                        "ProductName": "Prod 2",
                        "ItemDiscount": "0",
                        "Quantity": "5",
                        "TotalItemPrice": "449.75"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Based on the json I have made a ui for you to show the order details :

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: HomePage());
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Order> ordersList = List();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData();
  }

  getData() async {
    String data =
        await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("json/parse.json");

    Map newMap = json.decode(data);

    newMap['data'].forEach((k, v) {
      
      v.forEach((key, val) {
        String ordername = key;
        List<Item> items = List();
       
        
        val['Items'].forEach((key, value) {
          print('sample');
          Item item = Item(
            productNumber: key,
            productName: value['ProductName'],
            itemDiscount: value['ItemDiscount'],
            quantity: value['Quantity'],
            totalItemPrice: value['TotalItemPrice'],
          );
          items.add(item);

          print(key);
          print(value);
          print('length is :${items.length}');
        });

        Order order = Order(
            orderId: val['OrderId'],
            orderName: ordername,
            total: val['total'],
            items: items);

        ordersList.add(order);
      });
    });
    setState(() {});

    print('This is the list : count ${ordersList.length}');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: ordersList.length,
          shrinkWrap: true,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            var order = ordersList[index];
            return Card(
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Order Name : ${order.orderName}'),
                  Text('Order Id : ${order.orderId}'),
                  Text('Order total : ${order.total}'),
                  Text('Order Items: ${order.items.length}')
                ],
              ),
            );
          }),
    ));
  }
}

class Order {
  final String orderName;
  final String orderId;
  final String total;
  final List<Item> items;

  Order({this.orderName, this.orderId, this.total, this.items});
}

class Item {
  Item({
    this.productName,
    this.itemDiscount,
    this.quantity,
    this.totalItemPrice,
    this.productNumber,
  });
  String productNumber;
  String productName;
  String itemDiscount;
  String quantity;
  String totalItemPrice;
}
```

Maybe just what I am confused is the json you provided is correct please check as it has order6 inside the order 4, and there are to caring parameters for OrderSubTotal and total just let me know if things are right.

Just check it out and let me know if it works